# How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process

Tags: .net, process, 32bit-64bit, syswow64

I am trying to run a 64 bit executable (java.exe) from our 32-bit .NET application. I am using `Process` class and invoking `cmd /c <command name>` in order to support all possible commands (like `dir`, `cd` etc).

The problem is that on my machine I installed 64-bit version of JRE and java.exe is only available from `C:\Windows\System32` folder (x64). I have tried explicily starting 64 bit version of `cmd.exe` by calling `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` but it gets redirected to `SysWOW64` due to calling process being 32 bit.

Is there anything else I can do to get this to work?

**EDIT** The whole `cmd /c` thing is a bit of a red herring. It is not part of the problem, being able to run 64 bit executables is.

Comment: This answer might bring more light into this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466850/the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-after-disabling-wow64-redirection

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466850/the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-after-disabling-wow64-redirection

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can temporarily disable filesystem redirection around the call to Process.Start, the appropriate API's to P/Invoke are [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection.html) and [Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection.html).

Another option is to use %windir%\sysnative, which is available on Windows Vista and above.

Comment: Sounds scary, i'll give it a go :)

Comment: Indeed this works. I can't believe this is the official way of doing it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28VS.85%29.aspx - MSDN demonstrates using this function for precisely this purpose.

Comment: Cool, sysnative worked too, i ll probably use that in the final version.

Comment: Use `sysnative`, definitely. Even though `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` only affects the current thread, it's the more complicated way, and requires you to use P/Invoke (which also means you need full trust). How did Java end up in the system directory anyway? Shouldn't it be in program files, like all the well behaving applications?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `sysnative` only exists for 32-bit processes. If your process is 64-bit, you will get a File not found exception. So you have to check your bitness anyway before accessing `sysnative`, which is a shame because it would be so much better if it resolved to the same folder regardless of your own bitness.

Comment: universal access to `sysnative` from 32-bit and 64-bit processes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67942292/1351740

Answer (score 18):

What you do is you use %windir%\sysnative to resolve 64-bit CMD.EXE and then you launch your other 64-bit program via "/c" command line option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To further clarify use: C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe will run what is effectively in C:\Windows\System32 without redirection. Further info: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm

Comment: sysnative-Folder is not present in Windows10

Comment: Nor Windows 7 or 8.1

Comment: You can't see it, but you can cd to c:\windows\sysnative in wnidows 10, or run c:\windows\sysnative\notepad.exe for example and get the 64-bit one, if you're in 32 bit cmd for example (or the 32 bit kace client).  Good tip.

Answer (score 7):

```
c:\>set proc
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 70 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=4601

c:\>c:\windows\sysnative\cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\>set proc
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 70 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=4601

c:\>
```

Answer (score 4):

**To run process/script via 64-bit cmd.exe** you might use this:

`%windir%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c %windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c ProgramToRun parameters`

This solution **works universally from both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.**

---

p.s.
%windir%\sysnative exists only in 32-bit processes.
%windir%\SysWOW64 exists both in 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

Comment: When in 64-bit environment, the first cmd.exe (`%windir%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`) is started as a 32-bit version. While in 32-bit environment, the first cmd.exe is started as 32-bit version of course. Eventually, the second cmd.exe (`%windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe`) is always started from a 32-bit envrionment and the `%windir%\sysnative` pointing to 64-bit version. Hope this explanation could help those who are not familiar with Windows file system redirection (e.g. like me). Anyway, what a nice and clean universal solution to start a 64-bit app.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this might help..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(VS.85).aspx

Note that if the application is manifested to show the UAC prompt, then redirection will not take place. And also some folders are exempt from redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way inside a cmd window to switch to 64 bit cmd in the event you find yourself in the 32 bit version:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 %windir%\sysnative\cmd
```

Or to *conditionally* execute in 64 bit from inside a 32 bit batch process:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 "%windir%\sysnative\cmd" /c "someProgram"
```

Or even better:

```
set "commands=multiple commands & to execute"
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 ( "%windir%\sysnative\cmd" /c "%commands%" ) else ( %commands% )
```

Answer (score 0):

"sysnative" seems to have some drawbacks.

Example:
When you start powershell.exe via `C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` some CmdLets like `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage" and "Get-WindowsCapability` don't work / throw exceptions:

> Get-AppxProvisionedPackage: "Error setting current directory to
>   "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0": Part of the path
>   "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" could not be found"
>
> (translated from German "Fehler beim Festlegen des aktuellen
>   Verzeichnisses auf "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0": Ein
>   Teil des Pfades "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" konnte
>   nicht gefunden werden.")

There might be similar problems running other processes than powershell (whenever the process source directory is important?) ...