# Unable to launch onscreen keyboard (osk.exe) from a 32-bit process on Win7 x64

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, 64-bit, on-screen-keyboard

90% of the time I am unable to launch `osk.exe` from a 32bit process on `Win7 x64`. Originally the code was just using:

```
Process.Launch("osk.exe");
```

Which won't work on x64 because of the directory virtualization. Not a problem I thought, I'll just disable virtualization, launch the app, and enable it again, which I *thought* was the correct way to do things. I also added some code to bring the keyboard back up if it has been minimized (which works fine) - the code (in a sample WPF app) now looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace KeyboardTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

        private const UInt32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        private const UInt32 SC_RESTORE = 0xf120;
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private string OnScreenKeyboadApplication = "osk.exe";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void KeyboardButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the name of the On screen keyboard
            string processName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OnScreenKeyboadApplication);

            // Check whether the application is not running 
            var query = from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                        where process.ProcessName == processName
                        select process;

            var keyboardProcess = query.FirstOrDefault();

            // launch it if it doesn't exist
            if (keyboardProcess == null)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(); ;
                bool sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = false;

                // Disable x64 directory virtualization if we're on x64,
                // otherwise keyboard launch will fail.
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                {
                    sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
                }

                // osk.exe is in windows/system folder. So we can directky call it without path
                using (Process osk = new Process())
                {
                    osk.StartInfo.FileName = OnScreenKeyboadApplication;
                    osk.Start();
                    osk.WaitForInputIdle(2000);
                }

                // Re-enable directory virtualisation if it was disabled.
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                    if (sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect)
                        Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
            }
            else
            {
                // Bring keyboard to the front if it's already running
                var windowHandle = keyboardProcess.MainWindowHandle;
                SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, new IntPtr(SC_RESTORE), new IntPtr(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this code, most of the time, throws the following exception on `osk.Start()`:

> The specified procedure could not be found
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

I've tried putting long Thread.Sleep commands in around the osk.Start line, just to make sure it wasn't a race condition, but the same problem persists. Can anyone spot where I'm doing something wrong, or provide an alternative solution for this? It *seems* to work fine launching Notepad, it just won't play ball with the onscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a very solid explanation for the exact error message you are getting.  But disabling redirection is going to mess up the .NET framework.  By default, Process.Start() P/Invokes the ShellExecuteEx() API function to start the process.  This function lives in shell32.dll, a DLL that might have to be loaded if that wasn't previously done.  You'll get the wrong one when you disable redirection.

A workaround for that is to set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false.  You don't need it here.

Clearly, disabling redirection is a risky approach with side-effects you cannot really predict.  There are *lots* of DLLs that get demand-loaded.  A very small helper EXE that you compile with Platform Target = Any CPU can solve your problem.

Comment: Setting UseShellExec to false means it crashes with something along the lines of "executing without shellexec requires elevation"

Comment: I was thinking that another exe might be the only way out, unless someone could think of another way.

Comment: Odd, sounds like another side-effect.  Yes, that helper should work.

Comment: A side note: on `Windows 10 1607` and **older** - checking if `c:\windows\system32\osk.exe` exists before running it, will return **true**, but newer versions will return **false**. so, You'll better check with `c:\windows\sysnative\osk.exe`.

Answer (score 15):

A 32 bit application running on a 64 bit operating system should start the 64 bit version of osk.exe. 
Below you see a code snipped written in C# to start the correct on screen keyboard.

```
    private static void ShowKeyboard()
    {
        var path64 = @"C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_06b1c513739fb828\osk.exe";
        var path32 = @"C:\windows\system32\osk.exe";
        var path = (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) ? path64 : path32;
        Process.Start(path);
    }
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, but the amd64_microsoft.... path was named just a little differently for me. I have to search directories using pattern matching: `Path.Combine(Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "winsxs"), "amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_*")[0], "osk.exe")`

Comment: Hi @HotN your code works for me, thank you. Also can you suggest if i can change the position of my on screen keyboard using code ?

Comment: @ashishbharwal001 I don't have any code to do so handy, but you should be able to set the keyboard size and position using pinvoke functions. `SetWindowPos` (https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) should do what you're looking for. You can get the window handle to pass in using `Process.GetProcessesByName("osk.exe")[0].MainWindowHandle`.

Comment: I was getting the error: `the system cannot find the file specified` in App.xaml file in my wpf application. The reason was just calling Process.Start("osk.exe"). It was working on 32bit OS but not 64bit. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is my code

```
            var path64 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "winsxs"), "amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_*")[0], "osk.exe");
            var path32 = @"C:\windows\system32\osk.exe";
            var path = (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) ? path64 : path32;
            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
                Process.Start(path);
            }
```

Comment: As good stack-overflow practice, please try to explain either what piece of code you have written or why your answer is better than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Certain things are going on under the hood that require you to start osk.exe from an MTA thread. The reason seems to be that a call to [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28VS.85%29.aspx) only affects the current thread. However, under certain conditions, `Process.Start` will create the new process from a separate thread, e.g. when `UseShellExecute` is set to false and also when being called from an STA thread as it seems.

The code below checks the apartment state and then makes sure to start the On-Screen Keyboard from an MTA thread:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, 
        UInt32 Msg, 
        IntPtr wParam, 
        IntPtr lParam);
    private const UInt32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    private const UInt32 SC_RESTORE = 0xf120;

    private const string OnScreenKeyboardExe = "osk.exe";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OnScreenKeyboardExe));

        if (p.Length == 0)
        {
            // we must start osk from an MTA thread
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA)
            {
                ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(StartOsk);
                Thread thread = new Thread(start);
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
            else
            {
                StartOsk();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // there might be a race condition if the process terminated 
            // meanwhile -> proper exception handling should be added
            //
            SendMessage(p[0].MainWindowHandle, 
                WM_SYSCOMMAND, new IntPtr(SC_RESTORE), new IntPtr(0));
        }
    }

    static void StartOsk()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(); ;
        bool sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = false;

        // Disable x64 directory virtualization if we're on x64,
        // otherwise keyboard launch will fail.
        if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect = 
                Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
        }


        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = OnScreenKeyboardExe;
        // We must use ShellExecute to start osk from the current thread
        // with psi.UseShellExecute = false the CreateProcessWithLogon API 
        // would be used which handles process creation on a separate thread 
        // where the above call to Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection would not 
        // have any effect.
        //
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(psi);

        // Re-enable directory virtualisation if it was disabled.
        if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            if (sucessfullyDisabledWow64Redirect)
                Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, odd, I can run it without elevation normally, and the code I posted *does* work, just not very often. I'll add elevation see if that helps.Thanks.

Comment: When starting osk via `Process.Start()` or manually from a command prompt I got an error stating "Could not start On-Screen Keyboard." in both cases.

Comment: Well, I guess elevation just gives the osk.exe process a different (64-bit) parent so that FS-redirects are no longer a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy method:

Run this batch file on the side  (started from 64 bit explorer) :

```
:lab0
TIMEOUT /T 1 >nul
if exist oskstart.tmp goto lab2
goto lab0
:lab2
del oskstart.tmp
osk
goto lab0
```

Create file oskstart.tmp when you need the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Here is an up to date answer based on:
[How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process/)

The code is the following:

```
string system32 = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "Sysnative" : "System32";
string windir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%");
Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = Path.Combine(windir, system32, "cmd.exe"),
    Arguments = "/c start osk.exe"
});
proc.WaitForExit();
```

The addition of `start` is required to start On-Screen Keyboard without waiting for it to close.

Running `osk.exe` from the actual System32 folder should be ok regardless of OS and app bitness. Based on the following post, System32 folder contains 64 bit applications on 64 bit Windows: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-syswow64-64-bit-windows/

I have tested the code inside a .NET Framework 4.7.2 app with x86/x64/Any CPU build configuration, on Windows 10 Pro 21H2 (64 bit).

Answer (score -1):

For those who are facing "Could not start On-Screen Keyboard.", change your project's Platform Target to Any CPU.

Comment: The whole point of this question is about trying to do this with a 32bit process on a 64-bit o/s - so just switching to Any CPU doesn't help!

Comment: Microsoft recommends you do NOT do this anymore. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx