# Calling the on-screen keyboard using a button in C#

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv, on-screen-keyboard

I am creating a windows application using C#, where in a button on the GUI when clicked, should display the on-screen keyboard.

Would appreciate if any help is granted. thanks.

Also, since I am mostly using Emgu Cv library for the rest of my app, Can we simply use it for calling the On-screen keyboard?

Comment: `Process.Start("osk.exe");` should work on all Windows systems.

Comment: @CodyGray unfortunately not working when building for x86 (I am forced due to GeckoFx)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In C#, you can simply write the following line of code to invoke the on-screen keyboard application that comes with Windows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

You can find more help [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/138e57d3-7ee3-42a1-b43d-65900a56cb57).

Comment: I just tried it in win10 (creators update) and it works

Comment: On Windows 10 you need to change Build settings to perform target in x64 like @Hassan Rahman said

Comment: The solution  in this link worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929255/unable-to-launch-onscreen-keyboard-osk-exe-from-a-32-bit-process-on-win7-x64

Answer (score 14):

For Windows 10 x64, You have set the project build to x64 as shown in image.

[image]

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(
            ((Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\osk.exe"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems trying to run osk within and endpoint. This works for me:

```
var onScreenKeyboardProcess = new ProcessStartInfo("osk.exe")
{                    
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(onScreenKeyboardProcess);
```