# "The specified procedure could not be found " after disabling wow64 redirection

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I am running a 32bit application on a x64 system.(windows 7)
I am trying to run windows backup which is located at: c:\System32\sdclt.exe.
Because I am running as a 32 bit process I have to disable WOW64 redirection (using Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection) .
The problem is that after disabling the wow64 redirection I get "The specified procedure could not be found" error.

My guess is that somehow when disabling the redirection the sdclt.exe cannot load all its dependent dll's.

notes:
1. this happens only in case I'm not running with elevated priviliges.
2. I am setting "use shell execute" to true because I wanna let users to use my app with no elevated priviliges.
2. this error won't happen when compiling to 64 bit.

Answer (score 6):

Disabling file redirection is a precarious business. You are doing it here in order for your 32 bit process to be able to see the file located in `system32`. Normally any reference to that folder from a 32 bit process would be redirected to `SysWOW64`. But, as you discovered, disabling file redirection breaks other links in the chain.

The best solution that I know is to use the special `%windir%\sysnative` alias to be able to locate the true system32 directory. Don't disable file redirection and simply pass `%windir%\sysnative\sdclt.exe` when spawning the process.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) for file redirection says:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.
>
> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP**:  The Sysnative alias was added starting with Windows Vista.

The final warning effectively means that `%windir%\Sysnative` is not recognised on XP64, unless the machine has been serviced with the MS hotfix that back-fits `%windir%\Sysnative` to that OS. In practice this doesn't matter because the XP64 installed base is vanishingly small.

The only other solution that I am aware of is to create your own dedicated launcher that is a 64 bit process. If you place that launcher in a folder that is not subject to file redirection then you can call that launcher from your 32 bit process and then the launcher is able to see the 64 bit system directory. I think you would have to use this approach if you needed to support XP64.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! The problem is that now when running not as administrator I get "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: the weird thing is that this problem reproduce only on 1 machine out of 20. and it never happen when running as admin.

Comment: Impossible to tell from here. But disabling file redirection is just a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: What even make it weirder is that when using your approach (sysnative) File.exist return true no mather if I run as admin or not. but when trying to launch the process I get "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: yes... btw I don't if it means anything but I get the system cannot find the *path* specified, and not the *file* as I mentioned before..

Comment: sysnative only works from a 32 bit process. You sure you aren't using AnyCPU or anything like that?

Comment: yes. I am absolutely sure (besides it does work when I am using file.exist). but maybe the problem is that when creating a new process with shell execute the sysnative is not recognize.

Comment: Perhaps your shell execute code doesn't like `%windir%`. Try plain old `C:\Windows` just to remove that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I noticed problem only occurred on Windows 7 x64 systems without SP1 installed.  On systems where problem occurred, upgrading to SP1 fixed it.