# Opening explorer.exe from a jump task using 32 bit task on 64 bit OS

Tags: .net, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, jump-list

I have a 32 bit application that I want to register opening "explorer.exe" as a jump task.  It works fine on 32 bit Windows 7, but in 64 bit Windows, it gives an error "C:\Windows\system32\explorer.exe Unspecified error".

Since Explorer's full path is "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\explorer.exe", I assume this is a result of Windows seeing the 32 bit emulated path at at run time, but the jump list needs the full 64 bit path.  Is there a simple way to build this jumplist that will work on a 64 bit OS?

I guess I could do a check of Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem and hardcode the location to "C:\Windows\SysWow64" if it's set, but I it's bad to be using hardcoded paths.

```
string exe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string current = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
var jl = new System.Windows.Shell.JumpList();
jl.ShowFrequentCategory = false;
jl.ShowRecentCategory = false;
jl.BeginInit();
jl.JumpItems.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new System.Windows.Shell.JumpTask
        {
            Title = "Explore",
            ApplicationPath = "explorer.exe",
            IconResourcePath = "explorer.exe",
            Arguments = "/select,\"" + exe,
            WorkingDirectory = current,
        },
        // other jump tasks here
    });
jl.EndInit();
jl.Apply();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here [How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process?rq=1)

The "sysnative" thing doesn't work in this scenario, but disabling filesystem redirection temporarily works:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
    try
    {
        // Add jump list code
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(ptr);
    }
```