# How can i run rundll32 64bit process from c#

Tags: c#, windows, 32bit-64bit, drivers, rundll32

I need install driver into system32\drivers, but if i'm using default install from rundll32 from c#, driver is installing into syswow64. That is my code:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.Verb = "RunAs";
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"/C rundll32.exe SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 " + file;
            var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
```

How can i run this process like 64bit process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process)

Comment: Yuck, Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() is a very ugly answer, very unsafe in a .NET app.  Use sysnative or just plain let your program run as a 64-bit process by removing the jitter forcing.  Which is the best way, you need to obtain UAC elevation so using a little helper process with the correct manifest is often needed anyway.