# 32 bit process launches 64 bit process that uses 64 bit DLL. Call tio DLL fails

Tags: c++, windows, process, 64-bit

I have a 64 bit command line utility (EXE) built under Microsoft VC++ 12
That 64-bit EXE calls 64-bit DLLs during its work.
I can launch the 64 bit EXE from a command line and everything is working fine.

Now I need to call this 64 bit EXE from a 32-bit COM object.
The 64-bit EXE is called fine and performs some actions,
HOwever, at the moment 64 bit EXE has to get information from 64 bit DLL , then the 64 bit EXE stops working.

What can be the reason why 64 bit EXE regular code works when called from 32-bit COM object, but access to 64bit DLL (called from 64 bit EXE) fails 
when 64 bit EXE is called from 32 bit COM object ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process)

Comment: Please be more specific about what goes wrong.  Does the DLL load fail?  What is the error code?