# Createprocess() of "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe" fails with error=2

Tags: c, windows, createprocess, system32

On a Windows-10 machine, I am trying to run ssh.exe as a child process using createprocess, something like the below snippet:

```
// Create the child process.
bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
    child_cmd,     // command line 
    NULL,          // process security attributes 
    NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
    TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
    0,             // creation flags 
    NULL,          // use parent's environment 
    NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
    &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
    &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

                   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
if (!bSuccess)
{
    ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
    return NULL;
}
```

The CreateProcess API fails with error 2 (file not found) when child_cmd parameter contains “C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe”. What is puzzling is that, this file - ‘C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe’ - exists on the machine; yet, CreateProcess() reports error 2. If I copied ‘C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe’ [from command prompt] to some other location, say ‘C:\tmp\System32_OpenSSH\ssh.exe’ and then call CreateProcess() with child_cmd parameter containing “C:\\tmp\\System32_OpenSSH\\ssh.exe”, the exact same program works like a charm. Any clue what is going on here? Are there any OS imposed restrictions regarding C:\Windows\system32 folder?

I faced similar problem with file copy as well - system("copy C:\\Windows\\system32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe OpenSSH_ssh.exe").

Comment: error code 2 on Win32 is `"The system cannot find the file specified. "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest that while you do indeed have a binary named `ssh.exe` in your `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` folder, your compiled code is running as 32-bit, but your OS is 64-bit.

32-bit code running on a 64-bit OS gets a redirection of the file system for certain folders.  Such that any attempt to access `C:\Windows\System32` is getting mapped to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  I'm guessing don't have a copy of `ssh.exe` in your `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenSSH` folder. (Appears to be the case for me too.)

If you compile your code as 64-bit, it would likely work.  Off the top of my head, I don't remember the rules if a 32-bit process is allowed to "create" a 64-bit process. (I would think so - right?)     But a quick Google references [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process).  Looks like there are [some APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) that can be invoked to disable file system redirection.

Comment: WOW64 processes also have the "%SystemRoot%\SysNative" virtual path for accessing the native "%SystemRoot%\System32" directory. Unfortunately native processes do not have "SysNative".

Comment: Thanks very much! So, it is indeed the OS magic/restriction. Unfortunately, I don't have the flexibility to change my code to 64-bit due to other dependencies. So, I will implement the methods to disable file system redirection. Thanks for the help and valuable pointers!

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes in the path by double slashes.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The slashes were escaped with double-slashes in the program. The text editor here garbled them up. I edited the question to add them back here in the question.

Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No; your answer helped me notice missing double-slashes in the question, and correct it.