Setup.exe unpacks MSI wrong, but ONLY when run as NT Authority/System
I have a PSADT script (which naturally runs as 64bit) that runs setup.exe ($File.FullName is the fullpath to the file) to install an application called "ReadSoft Forms".
I need to use PSADT, because it allows me to do other stuff after installation and before and so on.
Execute-Process -Path $File.FullName -parameters "/S /v`"/qn /l*v `"$Log`"`"" -Passthru

This command works perfectly when the script is run via a local administrator account, because the file is unpacked by the .exe to:

C:\Users\your-admin-account-here\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations{EF511B63-0691-417B-BA08-C154550610A0}\ReadSoft FORMS 5-3.msi

But if I run the exact same script via SYSTEM account/SCCM/intune with:
Deploy-Application.exe -DeploymentType Install

I see this in the logs showing it launched my installer via syswow64:

Verbose logging started: 31/07/2024  15:04:06  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSIEXEC.EXE

It then fails to find the msi file, because it's looking for it in C:\windows\system32:

MSI (s) (54:40) [15:04:06:257]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations{EF511B63-0691-417B-BA08-C154550610A0}\ReadSoft FORMS 5-3.msi 3: -2147287037

even though the file was actually unpacked (and never used) here:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations{EF511B63-0691-417B-BA08-C154550610A0}\ReadSoft FORMS 5-3.msi

The Deploy-Application tool has previously always run everything I throw at it as 64bit, even though the Intune management engine will run things as 32bit by default. All my other Intune packages work flawlessly in this manner; they install applications 64bit as expected, etc.
I'm certain this is a sysnative problem, but i have no idea how to solve it.
I tried to modify the script to instead, launch the Setup.exe as 32bit, via:
start-job -scriptblock $scriptblock -RunAs32

Based on Start-transcript i can see it does launch Powershell as 32bit, and runs the setup.exe, produces the msiexec log etc. But then in the msiexec log I have the exact same problem as above.
How can I get this installer to run via PSADT, under the system account?

The creator's GitHub location might be a good place to ask. https://github.com/PSAppDeployToolkit/PSAppDeployToolkit/issues

the script is running as a 32 bit process instead of a 64 bit process.  See if following helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process
